# anyone know why my tor wont connect

Tags: configuration, connection

```
4/13/19, 23:25:23.451 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/13/19, 23:25:23.451 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/13/19, 23:25:23.451 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/13/19, 23:25:23.451 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/13/19, 23:25:23.451 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/13/19, 23:25:23.451 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.2" 
4/13/19, 23:25:23.451 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay 
4/13/19, 23:25:23.508 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay 
4/13/19, 23:25:35.572 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 74A910646BCEEFBCD2E874FC1DC997430F968145 at 199.58.81.140:443) 
4/13/19, 23:25:35.572 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
4/13/19, 23:25:35.572 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
4/13/19, 23:25:35.588 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/13/19, 23:25:35.589 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/13/19, 23:25:35.589 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking like Tor may be censored or otherwise blocked on your network. Your best bet is to use a bridge.

As a precaution though, before going all put just try restarting Tor browser or reinstalling, sometimes that helps

Answer (score 0):

Aktualisierung der Einstellungen für den Tor-Dienst
updating torrc custom configuration...
Orbot startet …
SUCCESS added control port event handler
SUCCESS connected to Tor control port.
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 20% (onehop_create): Establishing an encrypted directory connection
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 25% (requesting_status): Asking for networkstatus consensus
NOTICE: new bridge descriptor 'DockerObfs4Bridge' (fresh): $5A809B46B4F3FE1A9D23F6593307906A28EA480A~DockerObfs4Bridge [LM8gsgchJ0kRVQ4vRUL0Z0Q1zGPpUoUsAPPpmRd2f/M] at 75.90.21.147
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 30% (loading_status): Loading networkstatus consensus
NOTICE: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus.
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 40% (loading_keys): Loading authority key certs
NOTICE: The current consensus has no exit nodes. Tor can only build internal paths, such as paths to onion services.
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 45% (requesting_descriptors): Asking for relay descriptors
NOTICE: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/6920, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 100% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of end bw (no exits in consensus, using mid) = 0% of path bw.)
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 50% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors
NOTICE: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/6920, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 100% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of end bw (no exits in consensus, using mid) = 0% of path bw.)
NOTICE: The current consensus contains exit nodes. Tor can build exit and internal paths.
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 56% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 62% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 69% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 75% (enough_dirinfo): Loaded enough directory info to build circuits
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 76% (ap_conn_pt): Connecting to pluggable transport to build circuits
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 77% (ap_conn_done_pt): Connected to pluggable transport to build circuits
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 85% (ap_conn_done): Connected to a relay to build circuits
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 89% (ap_handshake): Finishing handshake with a relay to build circuits
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 90% (ap_handshake_done): Handshake finished with a relay to build circuits
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit
NOTICE: Bootstrapped

Comment: Can you please provide your custom configuration changes to make an answer more clear? It sounds like it was a real solution, but the solution details are undisclosed - please explain what have you changed